# Accelerated transfer feature in AWS amplify storage for react

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-amplify

I've enabled the accelerated transfer feature of my s3 bucket and I want to use its endpoint to read and write in that bucket. I am using AWS amplify to access the s3 bucket but cannot find enough resources on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The Amplify team is tracking this recent feature request here: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/4468